# SQL Server Group Row Number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I'm just wondering whether is possible to calculate unique row number for groups without using Group By...

My datasets as following...

```
FileSize         FileSize(KB/MB)
--------------------------------
             0      0.00 KB
             0      0.00 KB
            36      0.04 KB
            39      0.04 KB
           425      0.42 KB
           435      0.42 KB
           435      0.42 KB
       1000960      0.95 MB
       1001290      0.95 MB
    1266831853      1.27 GB
    1266831968      1.27 GB
    1312708509      1.31 GB
    1312711756      1.31 GB
    1367911756      1.36 GB
```

I would like to the datasets output as follow which required to sort the FileSize(KB/MB) by FileSize column in TabularModel...

```
FileSizeRank    FileSize    FileSize(KB/MB)
-------------------------------------------
    1                    0      0.00 KB
    1                    0      0.00 KB
    2                   36      0.04 KB
    2                   39      0.04 KB
    3                  425      0.42 KB
    3                  435      0.42 KB
    3                  435      0.42 KB
    4              1000960      0.95 MB
    4              1001290      0.95 MB
    5           1266831853      1.27 GB
    5           1266831968      1.27 GB
    6           1312708509      1.31 GB
    6           1312711756      1.31 GB
    7           1367911756      1.36 GB
```

I have tried this but it didn't help

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Filesize(KB/MB)] ORDER BY  FileSize) AS FileSizeRank
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You probably want `dense_rank() over (order BY [Filesize(KB/MB)])`

Comment: Many thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name, my case is a little bit different. I got all different sizes files and most of them are the same when I convert them from Byte to KB, MB and GB, please see the updated table above in the original post. I want to use this table in TabularModel and would like FileSize(KB/MB) column sort by the FileSizeRank column. I can't use the FileSize column for sorting as it has different numbers for same FileSize(KB/MB) text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY [Filesize(KB/MB)]) AS FileSizeRank
FROM tab
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/HSVPB31575)**

---

**EDIT:**

To avoid possible `ORDER BY` text problem I suggest to use:

```
SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY ROUND([File Size]/1000.0,2)) AS FileSizeRank
FROM tab;
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/SGGY65184)**

Comment: Many thanks, @Lukasz, it's really helpful insight, however, my case is a little bit different. 
I got all different sizes files and most of them as the same when I convert them from Byte to KB, MB and GB, please see the updated table above in the original post.
 
I want to use this table in TabularModel and would like FileSize(KB/MB) column sort by the FileSizeRank column.
I can't use the FileSize column for sorting as it has different numbers for same FileSize(KB/MB) text.